# Can I pass Powershell Get-ADUser -Properties in a variable?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'd like to do something like this, mainly for code readability:

```
$ADProperties = "extensionAttribute1,Department,Company,telephoneNumber"
$ADFilter = "{(objectClass -eq "user") -and (enabled -eq $True)}"

Get-ADUser -Filter $ADFilter -Properties $ADProperties
```

I get errors like:  `Get-Aduser : One or more properties are invalid.`

Seems like I've seen a way to pass either the **Filter** or **Properties** somehow, but can't find it now.

EDIT - This works for `-Properties`:

```
$ADProperties = "EmployeeID","EmployeeNumber","extensionAttribute1","Department"
```

(Thanks Eris) but this throws error:

```
$ADProperties = extensionAttribute1,Department,Company,telephoneNumber
```

Also, per Vasili, this works:

```
$str = @("foo","bar")
```

This works for `-Filter`

```
$ADFilter = {(objectClass -eq "user") -and (enabled -eq $True)}
```

Thanks everyone.
MOB

Comment: Try it without the quotes.

Comment: Not exactly without quotation marks, but make each property a separately quoted string. "extensionAttribute1", "Department" etc

Comment: Shouldn't need to quote them unless they have embedded spaces.

Answer (score 10):

The **Properties** parameter takes a `string[]` (array) data type, as such, it is expecting something more like this:

`@("extensionAttribute1","Department","Company","telephoneNumber")`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it if you construct your command in a String Variable like this:

```
$cmd = Get-ADUser -Filter $ADFilter -Properties $ADProperties
```

And then invoke it

```
invoke-command $cmd
```

Comment: @MOB If an answer was helpful to you, you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark to the left of this post.