# How to compare the results of Get-ADUser?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the results of two `Get-ADUser` queries stored in variables (they are querying two Active Directories).

What is the best way to compare them looking for an specific attribute and export to a CSV if they match? I tried to get it to work using nested `forEach` loops and comparing attributes with an `if` but it just appended to the csv all the results from both AD.

I am not currently home and I will upload my current code when I arrive but in pseudocode it was like this:

```cs
$res1 = get-adUser -filter{enabled -eq $true} -Properties     samAccountName, displayname, mail | select-object samAccountName, displayname, mail
$res2 = get-adUser -server ABC -filter{enabled -eq $true} -Properties samAccountName, displayname, mail | select-object samAccountName, displayname, mail

ForEach($u1 in $res1){
  ForEach($u2 in $res2){
    If($u1.mail -eq $u2.mail){
      Write-host $u1.mail $u2.mail
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $res1 -DifferenceObject $res2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
```

Answer (score 0):

While you're exporting the same set of properties you can use `Compare-Object` for this:

```cs
$props = @("samAccountName","displayName","mail")
$res1 = Get-ADUser -filter 'GivenName -eq "Robert"' -properties $props | Select-Object $props
$res2 = Get-ADUser -filter 'GivenName -like "Rob*"' -properties $props | Select-Object $props
$comp = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $res1 -DifferenceObject $res2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent
```

By default, `Compare-Object` shows you differences between object so you have to include equal objects and exclude different ones.

If for some reason, you don't want to compare all the properties you can specify `-Property` parameter like this:

```cs
# In that example you you want compare only displayName and mail
# SamAccountName might be different
$comp = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $res1 -DifferenceObject $res2 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -Property displayName,mail
```

---

#### Note:

As you might have noticed, I added one more improvement to your script - I saved all the properties to variable and then used it in `Get-ADUser` and `Select-Object` (idea taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21445810/9902555)). It might be useful if you want to add/remove any property. You can also do it like this:

```cs
$props = "samAccountName","displayName","mail"
```

But that only works for more than one parameter so I like to explicitly make it an array (more about this in [another helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11107477/9902555)).